# Change the property of objects in a List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have list of `Beam` objects. How can I change the `IsJoist` property of the beams when the `Width` property is greater than 40 using LINQ?

```
class Beam
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public bool IsJoist { get; set; }
}

var bm1 = new Beam { Width = 40 };
var bm2 = new Beam { Width = 50 };
var bm3 = new Beam { Width = 30 };
var bm4 = new Beam { Width = 60 };

var Beams = new List<Beam> { bm1, bm2, bm3, bm4 };
```

Here is what I have done but I'm only getting a List. I want the new list to be the same as the original one except that the IsJoist property for some beams will be set to true.

```
var result = Beams
    .Where(x => x.Width > 40)
    .Select(x => x.IsJoist = true)
    .ToList();
```

I was able to implement this as below. Is it ok since LINQ is meant for queries?

```
var result = Beams
    .Where(x => x.Width > 40)
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.IsJoist = true;
        return x;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You can't. The **entire point of those methods** is that they are functional. That is.. they have **no side effects**. Unless you use the "breaking" method `ForEach` on the `List<T>` type.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I actually found the answer and it isworking but I don'y know if it is good practice?

Comment: Never never never use a select to act like an update, that is a terrible programming practice. Use LINQ to *ask questions*, not to *make changes*.  If you want to make changes, use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks Eric, this was my main concern because it seemed very counter-intuitive to do such thing using LINQ.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If your solution must be completely Linq, you could do

```
Beams.Where(x => x.Width > 40).ToList().ForEach(b => b.IsJoist = true);
```

However, that is not an ideal way to implement this (@Jacob's answer is a better one).  Check out Eric Lippert's blog entry on the topic.  The most important lines for me are

> The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects. The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect.

https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Note that `ToList()` is called because `List<T>` provides a `ForEach()` method, while Linq in general does not offer such an extension method for the reasons Eric Lippert cites in that blog entry.

**UPDATE**

Your code both updates entities in the original list (changes IsJoist to *true* for certain conditions) and returns references to the objects that were updated.  If that is what you intended, the code functions.  However, Linq is designed with a functional paradigm in mind.  Introducing side effects within the context of a Linq expression violates the functional programming principal behind the extension methods.

Comment: Thanks. Can you look at my implementation too?

Comment: +1 for sir Lippert's quote. I couldn't remember who said something like that so I couldn't link to it in my comment.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the clarification.

Answer (score 11):

```
foreach(Beam beam in Beams.Where(x => x.Width > 40))
{
     beam.IsJoist = true;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be completely in LINQ.

Comment: @Vahid LINQ is only for querying and not for changing values.

Comment: The problem is that "beam" is declared as a new variable from the list. Yes, the value is being changed but not the one in the list.

Comment: Disagree. `beam` is a reference to the current object in the list. If you change any properties via the reference, you're changing the object.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose I want to change value of Property Selected to true for particular object then I can do like this

```
Beams.Where(x => x.Width > 40).FirstorDefault(z=>z.Selected = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

To be functionally pure, your linq would not alter the data that it is working on. This means that you would have to .Select(x=> new Beam(x) {IsJoist=true}). Then you would replace your original list with the results.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I've found is to `new` up a copy of the object, with the modifications in the select. It would be nice if there was a spread like in js.

Some untested code that should convey the idea:

```cs
public class Cat {
   public string Name;
   public bool IsFerrel;
}

List<Cat> cats = new{
   new{Name="Tame"},
   new{Name="Wild"}
};

return cats.Select(c => new Cat{
  Name = c.Name,
  IsFerrel = c.Name.Contains("Wild")
};
```

Essentially, this takes a functional approach of not mutating the object.

Comment: Looks like C# 10 adds the with operator which will accomplish this in shorter form: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression

Answer (score -1):

You can try this to change a property of all items in the list ( without any condition ).

```
Beams.All(b => b.IsJoist = true);
```

Comment: you can't do this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0832?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0832)